# How to bring data in suitable format for clustering in WEKA?

Tags: weka, arff, metadatatype

I've got about 10000 txt files. Every txt file contains video metadata in form:

```
Title: ...\n 
Video Id: ...\n
Url: ...\n
Duration: ...\n
```

and other attributes

I want to cluster these videos using their metadata with k means in weka, but I have problem preprocessing them. I load them with textDirectoryLoader, but I want the attributes to be Title, Photo Id, Url, Duration etc. Is there any way to bring data in this form in the arff file?

Comment: You can use programming languages to parse and format according to ARFF standard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just wanted to know if there was a way to do this via weka methods. I saved the file that was produced by weka textDirectoryLoader and tried to bring it in the correct form with Notepad++, but I still have many problems when I insert the new file in weka, because my data is a little bit complex. So I'll try to write a parser.